# Make Layout Non Clickable But Children Clickable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I've been working on a system overlay and I found that moving my imageview around the screen is a hassle using WindowManager.LayoutParams x and y, so I've decided to make a RelativeLayout with the height of the device to hold my imageview. The only problem is I want to make the Layout non clickable so that the activity below it can be clicked, but not the imageview itself as it launches an activity. Is there anyway to do this? Here is my code so far

```
 final RelativeLayout floaterLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    //this layout makes the relativelayout non clickable so that the activity below it can be clicked but it doesn't allow any children to be clicked either.
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.height = 2560;
    params.y = 0;

    floaterLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    floaterLayout.setAlpha(0.5f);
    floaterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(floaterLayout, params);
    ImageView view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    Util.setImageDrawable(view, R.drawable.floater_dots);
    floaterLayout.addView(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: as per my understanding your requirement is you want relative layout to be non clickable and children such as imageview to be clicked right? If so you can set the attribute clickable in xml to false for relative layout and setOnClickListener for imageView in java code

Comment: In my above code, I did set my relativelayout to not be clickable which worked. When I tried to click it in my emulator it wouldn't click which was half my goal, but I want any children of that layout be be clickable which didn't work when I tried to do something in the onClick of the child.

Answer (score 0):

@Nicolas you are creating a relative layout that's not added to your parent layout.Simply create a xml with a relativeLayout and an imageView. Set that imageView's onClickListener in java code. Through this the parent layout will be nonclickable and only imageview will be clickable

Comment: I should have probably mentioned I'm doing this within a service so I would still have to inflate the xml file to a view which would take up the screen. Therefore, I would still have the same problem as making the view I'm inflating to clickable in the WindowManager.LayoutParams determines whether the imageview I inflated is clickable. And If I make the view clickable then I cant click beneath it which is what I'm trying to avoid